# Syntax error in WITH clause and checking a query

Tags: sql, subquery, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have the following sql problem to solve:
Table: Events, with the following columns:
column name: business_id and type:int
column name: event_type and type: varchar
column name: occurences and type: int

(business_id, event_type) is the primary key of this table.
Each row in the table logs the info that an event of some type occured at some business for a number of times.

Write an SQL query to find all active businesses, where an active business is a business that has more than one event type with occurences greater than the average occurences of that event type among all businesses.

The query result format is in the following example:

Events table:
{"headers":{"Events":["business_id","event_type","occurences"]},"rows":{"Events":[[1,"reviews",7],[3,"reviews",3],[1,"ads",11],[2,"ads",7],[3,"ads",6],[1,"page views",3],[2,"page views",12]]}}

Result table for the above would have one column called business_id and it will have one row with 1.

Explanation: Average for 'reviews', 'ads' and 'page views' are (7+3)/2=5, (11+7+6)/3=8, (3+12)/2=7.5, respectively.
Only business with id 1 has 7 'reviews' events (more than 5) and 11 'ads' events (more than 8) so it is the only active business.

I wrote the following query:

```
WITH firstTable (event_type,avg_o) as (SELECT Events.event_type, avg(occurences) as avg_o
FROM Events
GROUP BY event_type)

WITH secondTable (business_id,event_type,avg2,g) as (SELECT Events.business_id, Events.event_type,firstTable.avg_o,
CASE
    WHEN Events.occurences>firstTable.avg_o THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END as g
FROM Events
JOIN firstTable
ON Events.event_type = firstTable.event_type)

WITH thirdTable as (SELECT business_id, sum(g) as g2
FROM secondTable
GROUP BY business_id)

SELECT business_id
FROM thirdTable
WHERE g2>1;
```

Questions, please:

1. There seems to be syntax errors in my query. Could you help me identify what they are and how to correct them?
2. Does my query work for solving the problem?
3. I believe there is a solution using window functions. Is that better, performance wise, than my approach that uses CTEs as you can see above?

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Aly

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. Please add **only** the tag for the database you are really using. If you get errors, then please **[edit]** your question and add the complete error message you get ([edit] your question, please do not put additional information into comments)

Comment: The `WITH` keyword is only needed once. To combine multiple CTEs, just separate them with commas: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your comment solved my syntax error, i.e., when I used one WITH keyword, it worked perfectly and gave the correct solution actually for all test cases so I guess it is correct. The only remaining question (which I put below as a comment on "GMB" 's answer is comparing the performance of my CTE solution with his window function one. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the excellent answer from GMB, here is a simpler CTE answer:

```
WITH 
firstTable (event_type,avg_o) as (SELECT Events.event_type, avg(occurences) as avg_o
FROM Events
GROUP BY Events.event_type)

SELECT Events.business_id
FROM Events
JOIN firstTable
ON Events.event_type=firstTable.event_type
WHERE occurences>avg_o
GROUP BY Events.business_id
Having count(*)>1;
```

And another simpler sub-query answer:

```
SELECT Events.business_id
FROM Events
JOIN (SELECT Events.event_type, avg(occurences) as avg_o
FROM Events
GROUP BY Events.event_type) as firstTable
ON Events.event_type=firstTable.event_type
WHERE occurences>avg_o
GROUP BY Events.business_id
Having count(*)>1;
```

Also, the main syntax error in my first answer in the question itself is, like  a_horse_with_no_name mentioned, that there should be only 1 WITH even with multiple CTEs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using window functions and aggregation:

```
select business_id
from (
    select e.*,
        avg(occurrences) over(partition by event_type) avg_occurences
    from events e
) e
where occurences > avg_occurences
group by business_id
having count(*) > 1
```

In the subquery, the window function computes the average of `occurences` over rows having the same `event_type`. Then, the outer query filters on rows where the value is greater than the avergae, aggregates by business, and retain groups with more than one row.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. My solution also works after I corrected the syntax error (which was that I needed to use WITH only once as " a_horse_with_no_name" mentioned). Now, the question is: Is your window function solution better, performance wise, than my approach that uses CTEs, or mine is better or they are the same?

Comment: @Aly: I would expect the window function solution to be more efficient, because it scans the table only once (as opposed to multiple times with the CTEs). It is also shorter to write... But you would need to assess that against your actual dataset.

Comment: Well, inspired by your answer, I was able to do a simpler 1 CTE answer and another 1 sub-query answer (see my answer below). Given that it is only 1 CTE (or 1 sub-query), would it be the same as the window function solution?

Comment: @Aly: that’s still two table scans, and a join.

Comment: @Aly . . . This answer is simpler than your answer and you should accept it.